# Margin note next to theorems

Tags: memoir, marginpar, marginnote, thmtools

I'm writing a math paper where I would like to give literature references next to theorems using `marginnote` or `marginpar`. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get them positioned in the right way (i.e. aligned with the title `Theorem x.y`) – no matter where I place my macro `\mathreferences`. Moreover, currently that macro also inserts where it is placed an additional new paragraph that I would like to get rid of without having to always comment out the blank line manually (without the macro, there is no new paragraph). How can I fix this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcounter{mathcounter}
\numberwithin{mathcounter}{chapter}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=2em,
  spacebelow=2em,
  postheadspace=1em,
  headfont=\upshape\bfseries,
  notefont=\mdseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
]{mytheoremstyle}

\declaretheorem[
  name={Theorem},
  style=mytheoremstyle,
  numberlike=mathcounter
]{theorem}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newcommand{\mathreferences}[1]{%
  \marginnote{%
    \footnotesize%
    \normalfont% no italic font, if we're using this inside a theorem
    \color{gray}
    \begin{flushleft}%
    % References: %
    #1%
    \end{flushleft}%
  }%
}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter{The chapter}
\section{The section}


\begin{theorem}
  \mathreferences{Give some references here}
  \label{foo}

  Let $(M^n, g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold, $Σ^{n-1} ⊂ M$ be a
  two-sided embedded hypersurface, possibly with boundary. Let $N$ be
  the – up to a sign unique – normal vector field of $Σ$. Then […]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** Following the comments, I played around some more and have settled with the following definition of `\mathreferences` for the time being:

```
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{\raggedrightmarginnote}

\newcommand{\mathreferences}[1]{%
  \marginnote{%
    \footnotesize%
    \normalfont% no italic font, if we're using this inside a theorem
    \color{gray}%
    #1%
  }%
}
```

Redefining `\raggedleftmarginnote` will always align content of the notes to the left, no matter whether they get displayed on the left or right margin in a double-sided document. (I previously used `\begin{flushleft}  …\end{flushleft}` for this but, unfortunately, this is messing up the vertical positioning.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to fix the issue with the blank lines, so I have resorted to always commenting out any blank lines following `\mathreferences`.

Comment: You are probably best of extending thmtools such that you can use `\begin{theorem}[balu-note=....]`, though currently I do not know how to implement this. When adding it inside the body it is very tricky to get the placement right of the side note. If on the otherhand we can have it run a, say, `\marginnote` as a part of typesetting the header, then we are done.

Comment: @daleif: Thank you for your comment! Can this possibly be done by passing a `preheadhook={}` to `\declaretheoremstyle` (or, alternatively, by calling `\addtotheorempreheadhook`)?

Comment: Since you probably don't want to have a list in the margin all the time, it probably needs to be a combination of adding a hook and then have it use data given by a key

Comment: This adds a `dlf=...` key, but still causes a line break after the header `\makeatletter
\thmt@define@thmuse@key{dlf}{\addtotheorempostheadhook[local]{\marginnote{\llap{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}test: {#1}}}}
\makeatother`

Comment: Thank you, this looks actually quite good! Also, having played around with your solution for a bit I noticed that it's actually the `\begin{flushleft} … \end{flushleft}` in my macro that's causing the vertical (mis-)alignment. Without it, it already looks quite good.

Comment: @daleif One more question: Do you happen to know how to align the `\footnotesize`'d text of my references with the normal-sized text of the theorem title? (I don't want their baselines to align but their mean lines or ascender heights.)

Comment: I was wrong, the vertical alignment still breaks when the theorem's title (as in `\begin{theorem}[Title]`) is very long – in this case, the margin note gets pushed down. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Add the \marginnote at the start of the title?

Comment: This will cause a compilation error – `thmtools` doesn't seem to allow this. (Meanwhile, using `\addtotheorempreheadhook` instead of `\addtotheorempostheadhook` will cause the marginnote to disappear.)

Comment: I alse tried the preheaderhook and had issues getting it to do something. Though might work with `\leavevmode\marginnote` (untested)

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick, unfortunately – the note is still not showing up. :\